# How to Enable and Disable a Command

Tags: c#, discord

I currently have a Discord Bot and i would like to be able to use a command to turn on and off another command e.g `?command off` & `?command on`.

I've had a look round on here and other sites but unable to find what i am looking for.

Could someone provide some examples or where to look please.

Comment: You could start "CommandA()" with a line like "IF(CommandAActive){//do stuff}, then make a "CommandB() flip 'CommandAActive' between 'true' and 'false' as desired

Comment: Keep a dictionary with the enabled commands and check if its enabled if its called?

Comment: That sounds sensible, i'll have a read on dictionary's and see what i can do thanks